# Project Euler #17 Python - "Number letter counts"

Tags: python, list, math

Here is the question:

If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.

If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were written out in words, how many letters would be used?

NOTE: Do not count spaces or hyphens. For example, 342 (three hundred and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen) contains 20 letters. The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in compliance with British usage.

I'm don't understand why my code won't output the correct answer. I've checked many times and I can't find anything that I've missed. Here is my code:

```
to_19 = [0,3,3,5,4,4,3,5,5,4,3,6,6,8,8,7,7,9,8,8]
tens = [0,3,6,6,5,5,5,7,6,6]
hundred = 7
thousand = 8
total = 0
for i in range(1,1000):
    u = i%10
    t = int(((i%100)-u) /10)
    h = int(((i%1000)-(t*10)-u) /100)
    print(h,t,u)

    if i < 20:                                                          #the number is less than 20
        total += to_19[i]
    elif h != 0 and (t != 0 or u != 0):                                 #the number is over 100 but not a multiple of 100
        if t == 0 or t == 1:                                            #the number is between x01 and x19
            total += to_19[h] + hundred + 3 + to_19[(t * 10) + u]
        else:                                                           #the number is between x20 and x99
            total += to_19[h] + hundred + 3 + tens[t] + to_19[u]
    elif t == 0 and u == 0:                                             #the number is a multiple of 100
        total += to_19[h] + hundred
    else:                                                               #the number is between 20 and 99
        total +=  tens[t] + to_19[u]

print(total+thousand)
#21121 is wrong
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `range(1,1000)` is from 1 to 999 not to 1000 inclusive

Comment: Yeah but I added a thousand to the final result on the last line

Comment: For easier reference as no answer is validated: the OP code is counting "thousand" letters instead of "one thousand" letters, so the missing 3 characters are there.

Answer (score 2):

The code seems reasonable enough. I didn't put much thought into your definition of `u`, `t`, and `h`, but it seems correct. The only thing I noticed you are missing is the "one" from "one thousand".

Comment: and you are adding "hundred" for one thousand.

Comment: Oh god. Yeaahhh. *facepalm*.  Thanks Brandon.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue is that you were not accounting for the 'and' in things such as 'One Hundred **and** Five'. In the example, it would be 20 letters by pure numbers, but it is 23. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
from num2words import num2words # num2words - Convert numbers to words in multiple languages
    
def pro_17():
   result = 0
   for i in range(1,1001):
        # Cancel spaces and add the length of the word
        result+=(len(''.join(''.join(num2words(i).split('-')).split(' '))))
   return result 

print(pro_17()) # reslut ---->  21124
```